# Redis Caching - Is it a bad practice to store duplicate data

Tags: node.js, redis, graphql

Is it a bad practice to store duplicate data in Redis cache?

I am experimenting with a GraphQL Caching solutions, but I have a few tables which I query by a combination of keys and never their primary key, and appears to be a bit of an issue for me.

Lets consider these tables

```
Products - id, ...
Images - id, productId, size
```

I need to be able to get the images ( multiple ) by `productId` or a single row by a combination of `productId` and `size`.

What I currently store is something in the form of

```
{
  images:productId:1:size:sm: {...},
  images:productId:1:size:xs: {...},
  images:productId:1: ['images:productId:1:size:sm', 'images:productId:1:size:xs']
}
```

The third object contains references to all of the available images in cache for the product, so I end up performing two queries to retrieve the data.

If I want one, I can directly go ahead and get it. If I want all of them, I first have to hit the third key, and then use the keys within it to get the actual objects.

Is this a bad idea? Should I bother with it, or just go with the simpler form

```
{
  images:productId:1:size:sm: {...},
  images:productId:1:size:xs: {...},
  images:productId:1: [ {...}, {...} ] // Copies of the two objects from above
}
```

To provide some context, some of these objects might become a bit large over time, because they might contain long text / html from Rich text editors.

I read that hashes compress data better, so I organized them in a way that they are placed in a single hash, that way invalidation becomes easier too ( I don't care about invalidating some of them, they will always be invalidated at once ).

It is a multi-tenant system, where I would be using a tenant id to scope the data to specific users.

Comment: It's a very common pattern to denormolize the data before storing to Redis.

Comment: So would you say that the first example would be the better approach?